# Listening to changes depends on the nested UID

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure in Firebase Realtime Database:

```
myCollection:
 - GAKlajGHAHjgghk
   - value: "My content"
   - users:
     - JAHGHJgjfKSJKKJGKJj
     - OPouiOHUIUOYHSioJhD
     - RJFvkJlkhgJTKghgJGh
 - LUhjkHSLKlkdlkd
   - value: "My content number 2"
   - users:
     - JAHGHJgjfKSJKKJGKJj
     - OPouiOHUIUOYHSioJhD
```

I want to write a function that listens for changes and new values

**When an item appears in the `myCollecion` directory which contains my user's UID in its subdirectory `users`, I should receive this object**

The reaction should occur when:

- a new item will be added to myCollection along with the corresponding UID
- when an existing item is changed

My code:

```
const myRef = firebase
  .database()
  .ref('myCollection/')
  .child('users')
  .orderByKey()
  .equalTo(this.state.user.uid);

myRef.on('value', snapshot => { ... });
```

The above code does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
const myRef = firebase
  .database()
  .ref('myCollection/')
  .child('GAKlajGHAHjgghk')
  .child('users')
  .orderByKey()
  .equalTo(this.state.user.uid);

myRef.on('value', snapshot => { ... });
```

You need to traverse the database from the top to the bottom without skipping a node. In your database you have:

```
myCollection/ -> GAKlajGHAHjgghk -> users
```

Comment: I don't know the UID position in myCollecion. When an object is created, the UID is created dynamically

Comment: Then first u need to retrieve the uid then you can query on the id under `users`

Comment: Unless the solution would be that after creating the object, I would also inform the user object that the object should be tracked. I would write these UIDs in a subcollection in the user object. Is this a good way?

Comment: The structure is a bit weird can u explain what u are trying to achieve